# Чередование максимальных, минимальных значений в массиве

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте товарищи программисты! Задача с Codewars,7 kyu.Max-min arrays.

Предоставлен массив уникальных элементов.

Задача: переупорядочить значения так, чтобы за первым максимальным значением следовало первое минимальное значение, за которым следовало второе максимальное значение, затем второе минимальное значение и т. Д.

Перепробовал все что можно. Как следует это оформить ?

Исходный массив: `[15,11,10,7,12]`

Ожидаемый результат: `[15,7,12,10,11]`

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, что перепробовали и какие именно возникают ошибки, а текже желаемый вывод.

Comment: Использовал  методы Math.max и Math.min.  А также еще Долго думал над способом решения и структуры кода. Ошибки были связанны с выводом самих чисел в правильном порядке, сейчас показать не смогу, но помню что пользовался вышеупомянутыми методами. Желаемый вывод чередование макс и мин значение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Сортируем массив по убыванию
2. Проходимся по массиву и пушим в `result` (результирующий массив) либо первый элемент массива (тоесть максимальный), либо последний элемент массива (тоесть минимальный).

Здесь важно проходится по исходному массиву и при этом его не изменять, именно поэтому в третьей строке используется деструктуризация массива `[...arr].sort((a,b)=>b-a)` что дает возможность скопировать значения исходного массива в новый массив `sorted`. Если этого не сделать, то в массив sorted запишется ссылка на массив `arr`, и после изменения `sorted` изменится и исходный массив `arr`

```js
function solve(arr){
    const result = []
    const sorted = [...arr].sort((a,b)=>b-a)

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(i % 2) {
        result.push(sorted.pop())
      } else {
        result.push(sorted.shift())
      }
    }
    return result
};

console.log(solve([15,11,10,7,12]))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое  за предоставленный способ решения Roman!  Все работает,спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [-4, 22, 3, 41, 5, 6].sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(arr.map((e, i) => arr[i % 2 === 0 ? arr.length - i / 2 - 1 : (i - 1) / 2]));
```